# Insert array content into database - php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I'm trying to insert in each row of database the variable $num which is an Array. I want to insert each array position in each row of database.

That's the code I have, and in the moment it is inserting the word "Array":

```
foreach($html2->find('small[class=menu-item__label__count]') as $aholder) {

$holderdes=$aholder->outertext;
}
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $holderdes, $num);
//preg_match_all('/(\([0-9]+)\)/',  $holderdes,$num);

echo print_r($num); 
echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$num."');</script>");
$insert="INSERT into spec_insert(designers) VALUES ('".$num."');";

$sql=mysql_query($insert);

if ($sql === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " ;
}
}
```

Comment: most likely `$num` is an array, and the result (number) you want is inside of it, you already have `print_r($num)`, just check whats inside and point to it directly. and stop using `mysql_*`. learn to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements, now

Comment: Inside of `print_r($num)` it's several: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 34 ) )`

Comment: then just point to it directly, `echo $num[0][0]`, its just nested.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert each array value to a specific column of DB table `spec_insert` then can use `foreach()` to retrieve the index value of array. Example

```
foreach($num as $val):
    if(is_array($val)):
        foreach($val as $v):
            $insert="INSERT into spec_insert(designers) VALUES ('".$v."');";
            $sql=mysql_query($insert);
        endforeach;
    else:
        $insert="INSERT into spec_insert(designers) VALUES ('".$val."');";
        $sql=mysql_query($insert);
    endif;
endforeach;
```