# multiple array insert into mysql database

Tags: mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to insert this type array into database please give suggestion how to do it: product code, color etc are the column names

```
$array = 
  array(
     'Product Code': A0857
     'Color: ': Green
     'Quantity' : 23
     )

array(
     'Product Code': A0857
     'Color: ': Green
     'Quantity' : 23
     )

);
```

Comment: add more desciption and sample data with expected result that you want

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched? Have you read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Did a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+insert+array+into+database&oq=stackoverflow+insert+array+into+database&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60.10543j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), some results to try: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054633/insert-array-into-mysql-database-with-php), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726447/insert-array-content-into-database-php),[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013211/how-to-insert-array-of-data-into-mysql-using-php),[4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185606/insert-array-into-database-in-a-single-row)

Comment: I search but not found any solution

Comment: what are column names of tables.